# Casting string format to date using time module

Tags: go

I've taken some date parts and concatenated them together to be yyyy-mm-dd. I've tried to parse that string as a date format so I can subtract it from another date to find out the difference.

This is the error I get:

```
.\main.go:67:17: cannot assign time.Time to full_date (type string) in multiple assignment
```

Any ideas?

```
full_date := year + "-" + month + "-" + day
full_date, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02", full_date)

currentTime := time.Now()
today := currentTime.Format("2006-01-02")

age := today.Sub(full_date).Hours() / 24
```

Comment: You declared `full_date` to be a string, you cannot assign a date to it. As a simple solution, use `full_date,err:=time.Parse("2006-01-02",year+"-"+month+"-"+day)` and remove the first line. Also as a side note: if you have year, month, day, you can simply convert those to integers and use time.Date to build a date.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone for helping on this. It works now and I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masters explained your errors in comments, Here is your code without bug

```
    full_date := year + "-" + month + "-" + day
    var parsedDate time.Time
    parsedDate, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02", full_date)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    today := time.Now()

    age := today.Sub(parsedDate).Hours() / 24
    fmt.Println("age is ", age)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is working perfectly!